# Como chamar uma activity a partir de uma BaseExpandableListAdapter?

Tags: android

Eu gostaria de chamar uma activity a partir do clique de um botão, porém não dá certo porque a classe de origem não é uma activity, e sim uma BaseExpandableListAdapter, existe uma forma de fazer isso?

Código:

```
holder.btnDetalhes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ExpandableAdapterMenuCompleto.this, DetalhesItemContaCliente.class);  
            StartActivity(i);           
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa passar o Context para sua classe Adapter e passar ele como parâmetro do Intent.

Comment: Rafael, seria interessante e tornaria a sua resposta mais completa, se mostrasse como isso é feito.